# In The Critique of Pure Reason, why does Kant use 5+7=12 as an example of synthetic a priori judgment?

Tags: kant

Sorry if this sounds stupid but I was wondering if there is any particular reason for choosing 5+7=12.

Comment: Not so far as I'm aware (part of my dissertation was on Kant), but Kant did make extensive notes and revisions to each of his works so there may be a reason he picked that. As to why it is math, I think there's answer to that more general question.

Comment: I doubt it. Presumably any particular sum wold have done like 2+3=5.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I think that the the whole argument might break down if he used 2+3=5;).

Comment: In all seriousness I think that he used this particular sum because it is sufficiently small, but also complicated enough (at least when compared to 1+1=2) that suggests that 5+7 is enough like the generic case of addition to illustrate that any sum would qualify (or for that matter any mathematical fact).

Answer (score 6):

This is old, but in case anybody finds it again: 5 + 7 = 12 is an example used in Plato's *Theaetetus*. I believe others referred to it as well.

It appears at 196a in the [Theaetetus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0171%3Atext%3DTheaet.%3Asection%3D196a):

"SOCRATES: [196a] I do not mean by setting before his eyes seven men and five men and considering them, or anything of that sort, but seven and five in the abstract, which we say are imprints in the block of wax, and in regard to which we deny the possibility of forming false opinions—taking these by themselves, do you imagine that anybody in the world has ever considered them, talking to himself and asking himself what their sum is, and that one person has said and thought eleven, and another twelve, or do all say and think that it is twelve?"

Comment: Hi. Where in _Theaetetus_?

Comment: @RamTobolski in http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1726/1726-h/1726-h.htm "do you think that no one ever put before his own mind five and seven?". Why Plato used that example we can only guess. I figure that it is not a trivial sum that one can perceive immediately (subitizing), but everybody remembers from childhood addition tables _and_ is very easy to check, i.e. good for exposition.